# Firebase phone number authentication in Electron js, Angular 5

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, angular5, electron

I am trying to implement Firebase Phone Number Authentication but there is a problem with environment such as I am using electron js.

Here is my code

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

sendPhoneNumber() {

const phoneNumber = '+' + this.phoneNumber;
const appVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('LoginPage-signInButton', {
    'size': 'invisible',
    'callback': (response) => {
      console.log('response', response)
    },
    'error-callback': (error) => {
      console.log('error', error);
    }
  });
  this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
    .then(confirmationResult => {
      console.log(confirmationResult);
    }) 
}
```

And I am getting this error

```
code: "auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment"
message: "RecaptchaVerifier is only supported in a browser HTTP/HTTPS environment."
```

are there any solutions for this problem or workaround?

Comment: Nobody can help you if you don't provide your code or explain clearly the problem you are facing, things you already tried etc.... Except if you want downvotes

Comment: there is no problem with my code because it is perfectly working in web

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, you seem to be trying to handle Phone authentication in your Electron Application. Phone authentication using Firebase JS library might not work based on how you are handling it in your Electron environment since the reCAPTCHA will be unable to verify the origin of your application. This is due to the fact that the origin will look like file://assets/index.html.

Firebase's phone authentication service for web depends on an app verifier interface: [https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.ApplicationVerifier) which RecaptchaVerifier implements.

Do this:

Open on browser, render the reCAPTCHA, get the reCAPTCHA token, close the browser and then pass it back to your the Electron app then implement your own firebase.auth.ApplicationVerifier.

Open a browser custom tab and redirect to your own and white-list in the Firebase Console where firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier will be rendered.
You then pass the reCAPTCHA response token back to your app. This guarantees that only your app can open it.

You need to listen to incoming links in your app and parse the reCAPTCHA token. Repackage it in a firebase.auth.ApplicationVerifier implementation. You can now pass it to signInWithPhoneNumber to complete sign-in.

Hope this helps.